# Headless UI Transition.child errors to "Did you forget to passthrough the `ref` to the actual DOM node"

Tags: tailwind-css, headless-ui

I'm building a sidebar with the Transition and Dialog Headless UI components.

[Transition docs](https://headlessui.com/react/transition)

When I break out the code that's passed between <Transition.Child> to it's own component. I get this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Did you forget to passthrough the `ref` to the actual DOM node?

Call Stack
eval
node_modules/@headlessui/react/dist/components/transitions/transition.js (1:3632)
```

Failing code:

```
<Transition.Child as={Fragment}>
    <Cart
      cancelButtonReference={cancelButtonReference}
      setCartOpen={setCartOpen}
      checkoutUrl={checkoutUrl}
      removeCartItem={removeCartItem}
      clearCart={clearCart}
      cartLoading={cartLoading}
      incrementCartItem={incrementCartItem}
      decrementCartItem={decrementCartItem}
      cartTotal={cartTotal}
      cart={cart}
    />
</Transition.Child>
```

Working code:

```
<Transition.Child as={Fragment}>
   <div>
     ...
   </div>
</Transition.Child>
```

I understand the error I believe, which is that when I break out the code to it's own component Transition.Child wants me to pass a ref so that React knows that it should render a component and not a fragment.

If I remove as={Fragment}, which makes the Transition default to a div the error goes away, but then I get an unneeded div..

What ref do I need to pass? This is what I don't get.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to pass a ref, but the component needs to accept one and set it on the actual element.
The `div` element will accept the ref, which is why that method works.

Try creating the `Cart` component using `React.forwardRef` and set the ref on the `div`.

```js
const Cart = React.forwardRef((props, forwardedRef) => {
  return (
    <div ref={forwardedRef}>
    ...
    </div>
  )
})
```